# Test Laravel Project from github in jenkins

Tags: git, laravel, jenkins

I am new to jenkins. I have commited my laravel project in bitbucket with git. I have integrate that project in jenkins. I have change some code in my project so that it can through error, and commit to bit bucket. I have now start to build in jenkins and get code which must through error, but jenkins create build successfully. jenkins also get latest updated code from git repositury after successfully run build. Can anyone help me what is the issue with this.

Comment: build will be successful if triggered using web hook but if you will check build no code will be there...build started and end simply so maybe it will be successful.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to convey. you mean to say that build run without running code, that is the reason that build is successful. if yes then tell me what to do to build by running code in jenkins.

Comment: my mean was like if your webhook fire jenkin and start build but jenkin not able to fetch gitlab code then jenkin give successful build status but nothing inside build artifact.

Comment: after build was successfully run and then if i check code in workspace then there is updated code which through and error.

Comment: ohhh okay ...thn